# Can't find setTimeOut from index.android.bundle

Tags: android, react-native

i'm using *react-native-cli* : 2.0.1 and *react-native* : 0.50.1.

When i'm using a debug version it's works fine, but when i'm trying to build a release version the apps don't start and crash. i already followed the [steps from the official website](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html). i try to debug it with *logcat* and get this error

[image]

Comment: Seems related to this open issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16704

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve this problem by upgrading react-native to 0.50.3 using [this step](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html) and now it's working perfectly !